# SSD to SSD migration, with some software installed on HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, migration

on my machine i have 1 SSD (C:) of 120 GB that is almost full, only 7 GB left. And another HDD (K:) 1 Terabyte, where i have installed some programs and where i store files. I've bought a new SSD (TOSHIBA SSD Q300 PRO 256GB) that comes with migration software, so my idea is to migrate C: to the new SSD, but i'm wondering if i can use the programs installed on K: or if i would encouter some problems with key register or something.
My machine is a i7 4770k 16 GB ram, with windows 10.
Thanks in advance for helps and suggestions.
Nico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nico. If you're cloning your 120GB SSD from `C:\` to another 256GB SSD, then there will be no issues. If this is a true 1:1 clone, then all registry, application pointers etc. will remain the same. The only **things I could think of** that may be an issue would be if applications are referrencing the SSD by some weird ID such as `serial` or `model`, which should not be a thing.

TL;DR? All the programs on `K:` should remain the same as they're not being touched.

Comment: Wonderful, of course I'd recommend keep the old SSD as is for approx 1 week to ensure no issues with your system! ^.^

Comment: Yes sure, i will wait some days before clear it. Thanks again